# I want to play sound while save a note

Tags: android-studio

> I want to play a sound while user save note in database here i'm using Media player to play sound and i have save the sounds file in raw folder.. Here is my Code

```
mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.save_effects); 

 @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId())
        {
            case R.id.note_save:
                mediaPlayer.start();
                    if (isEdit) {
                        updateNote(id,editText1.getText().toString(),editText2.getText().toString(),getDateTime(),Colors);
                    }else {
                        saveNote(editText1.getText().toString(),editText2.getText().toString(),getDateTime(),Colors);
                        break;
                    }

            case R.id.color:
                mediaPlayer.start();
                openColorPicker();
                break;


            case android.R.id.home:
                finish();
                break;

        }

        return true;
    }
```

> Here i'm getting the problem while clicking on save button not playing the sound but selecting color it play sounds please some one help me out of this problem..

Comment: maybe the missing break in your first case?

Comment: i have set break; if i set after mediaplayer.start then it wont save the note.

Comment: @MustafaShaikh try writing `mediaPlayer.start();` inside your if block and else block.

Comment: @MustafaShaikh try running your sound in a different thread, and have a close look in your logcat, it must be skipping frames, write a handler for mediaPlayer and start it inside that handler code goes like `new Handler().postDelayed({ mediaPlayer.start(); }, 10);` write this in your switch and after if-else write break. it will save and play your sound.

Comment: @Ashwani can you more elaborate in code section

Comment: @Ashwani i'm getting error after 'mediaPlayer.start();},10);'

Comment: @JacobCelestine its not playing the sounds it saving the note but not playing...

Comment: @MustafaShaikh what is the error?

Comment: @Ashwani there is no error in logcat  but not playing the sound while saving the note..